# How to execute a batch script using system command in a CGI application written in C, executed through web browser (Apache Server)

Tags: c, windows, apache, batch-file, cgi

Basically, I have written a CGI script in C, which contains a single system() function which is supposed to call a a batch file on the server where the EXE resides. A sample code I have written is as follows:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    //system("ROBOCOPY \\pdffiles \\\\10.6.202.88\\d$\\pdffiles /mov /ZB /XJ /FFT /MT /R:2 /W:5 /V");

    int t = 0;
    t= system("PDF_MOVE.bat");

    if(t == -1)
        {
            printf("file copy failure");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("file copy successfull");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

After I compile this code and put the generated .exe file in a folder in the Apache server.

Then when I try to hit this exe from a web browser by entering the full path of the exe in the browser(i.e http://10.6.202.111/path/to/file_copy_test.exe). This either tries to download the .exe file or gives me a Internal server error (500). The batch file contains the robocopy command that I have commented in the code. Also if I directly try to run the robocopy command through the system commmand, it fails as well.

- The Batch file itself runs properly.
- Running the robocopy command on the command line works correctly.
- If I execute the .exe file directly by double clicking it then it works correctly and calls the batch file properly.
- Only when trying to execute the .exe through the browser does this code fail.

What can I do to fix this, any Apache setting needs to be changed?. do the path to the folders needs to be changed?. I have tried putting ./ in front of the batch file name but then it fails on the command line as '.' is not recognised.

The Apache error log shows:

[cgi:error] [pid 10604:tid 1512] [client 172.24.2.82:56507] AH01215: operable program or batch file.\r: D:/itrade/app/user/file_copy_test.exe

---

After making the suggested changes, I realised that the source and destination paths provided for the Robocopy command were incorrect. Fixing that finally made it work.

The batch file I used:-

```
@echo off
(
net use \\10.6.202.88\d$ /user:Username password
ROBOCOPY D:\path\to\pdffiles \\10.6.202.88\d$\pdffiles /ZB /COPYALL /mov /XJ /FFT /MT /R:2 /W:5 /v /tee /log:robocopy_log.txt
EXIT
) >output.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Is your (Apache) server also running on windows?

Comment: @Rick Apache is also running on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know what the batch file outputs, but your C code is missing one vital important thing to conform to the CGI standards - a HTTP header.

The bare minimum you need to output is the Content-Type which since you're not expecting to output any HTML, might as well be "text/plain". The header is terminated with a blank line.

```
printf("Content-Type: text/plain\n\n");
```

Without that, Apache will treat anything you output as the header and return an error 500 if it doesn't understand it.

Configuration-wise, Apache needs to be told that CGI "scripts" exist in the folder you're trying to run it from and what extension they have.

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .exe
```

That might need to be in your main apache configuration inside a `<Directory ...>` block or in a ".htaccess" if you have allowed "users" to override the `Options` directive with `AllowOverride Options`

The executable also needs permissions to be read and executed by Apache.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you allow cgi execution by adding this to the VistualHost file or .htaccess file (see: https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/running-exe-and-batch-files-as-cgi-scripts-in-apache-under-windows)

```
AddHandler cgi-script .bat # add .exe if you wish
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymlinks
```

And why use a C program / .exe to execute a batch file? This batch file should also do the trick (to be honest I did not test this):

```
@echo off
echo Content-Type: text/html
echo.
CALL PDF_MOVE.bat || goto error
echo file copy successfull
goto :EOF
:error
echo file copy failure
```

Comment: I am using a C program .exe because my actual program is much more complicated and once the pdf's are moved it has to pick a pdf file from the new location and attach it to a email and send it. The program that iv'e shown above is just a basic test program,

Comment: Ok, then you should add the `Content-Type: <your mime>` output and add the `.exe` to the `AddHandler cgi-script` Apache config. Like @ChrisTurner 's answer.